# How to set IMAGES_STORE folder per Item in Scrapy 1.5

Tags: python, image, path, scrapy

Scrapy 1.5 allows setting an `IMAGES_STORE` setting for storing all downloaded media as explained in [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html)

I would like to be able to specify a custom folder per `Item` based on some values in the `Item`. Not knowing much about internals of Scrapy, I am not sure exactly which methods to override to accomplish this.

I thought about overriding [from_settings(cls, settings)](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/pipelines/images.py) but there I do not have access to `Item` yet.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by overriding `file_path` method. So in `IMAGES_STORE` I have the base path then I control the variable part from `file_path`. Something like below. However I had a typo first and `scrapy` silently ignored it without printing any errors even in debug... I don't know why? So it is best to start with a simple string for testing.

```
def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
    url = request.url
    image_guid = hashlib.sha1(to_bytes(url)).hexdigest()
    return '%s/full/%s.jpg' % ('my_custom_path', image_guid)
```